# What does the word "foliage" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from the description of a battle game:

> In the arena maps you will find the obstacles to take cover behind and
>   foliage you can hide in.

I am not sure if the word "foliage" means "leaves" here. How can one hide behind leaves?

Comment: a dictionary search could have answered this question

Comment: Addendum: "the obstacles" doesn't read right here (Indian English?). I'd drop the article.

Comment: It's a catch-all word to mean areas of vegetation. There's the foliage you can't hide in, like say a tall limbless tree; then there's foliage you can hide in, like dense shrubbery. It should be obvious to the player upon initial interactions which it would be. Some games use icons to indicate action can occur. Others rely on automatic proximity action-triggers.

Comment: How can one hide behind leaves? https://media.giphy.com/media/8wcF0byGIbzxOaIVAc/giphy.gif

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Foliage means the mass of green leaves on a plant. It is a non-count noun, unlike "leaf" which is countable.

So "hide in the foliage" means "hide in the bushes, shrubs, trees". If there are enough leaves, it is easy to hide among them.

Answer (score 2):

"Foliage" refers to general leafy plant matter, such as shrubs and bushes.

It makes more sense in the context of the difference between *Cover* and *Concealment* that is being highlighted by the sentence:

Cover is something that would provide *protection*, if someone knows you're behind it and starts shooting at you while you're behind solid *cover*, then you're hopefully safe.

Concealment is something that merely *keeps you from being seen easily*, and if someone knows you're behind something that offers mere concealment, rather than cover, and starts shooting at you, then you have little to no protection from it.